# How can I add Image and Text Header between the 'Scaffold' & 'StreamBuilder'?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Here I am trying to add Image and AppBar between the  'Scaffold' & 'StreamBuilder'. But when ever I 
  add Image or appBar the redLine error comes up that means the 'Scaffold' & 'StreamBuilder' does not 
  support AppBar and Image.

Now What should I do to have Image and AppBar at the above of  'StreamBuilder'

```
  class MyDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyDetailPageState createState() => new  _MyDetailPageState();
}

class _MyDetailPageState extends State<MyDetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

 // Want to add Image & appBar between the Scaffold & StreamBuilder .
  // How can I do this?

      body: StreamBuilder(
    stream:  Firestore.instance.collection('client').snapshots(),
    builder: (context,snapshot){
        return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
                DocumentSnapshot client =snapshot.data.documents[index];
                return
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                  child:
              Container(
                    height: 300,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purpleAccent,width: 2),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(width: 10),
                               Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text('Name:- ${client['fname']}\n', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 
                                 12.0,color: Colors.black),),
                                   Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Expanded(
                                        child: Text('detail:- ${client['purpose']}\n', style: new 
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,),),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )

                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )

                );
            },
        );
    },
    ),


    );
  }
}
```

Comment: u want an image inside the appbar? like an icon or a background image?

Answer (score 0):

```
home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      actions: <Widget>[
        // your widget
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

you could add an appBar to the Scaffold like this and you could learn more about Scaffold appBar from [AppBar class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)

Comment: But how can I add image beside the Appbar.

Answer (score 0):

where is your image comes from it is web URL or it is from the app files or the phone storage . In any case it so easy you could check

[Adding assets and images](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

[Display images from the internet](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/network-image)

Comment: I want to place the image above the AppBar and the image is store inside my file

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Chose when you want to put your image

```
appBar:AppBar(
  <your property>:<your image widget>
)
```